# Is it possible to override a method in WebSecurity class in C#?

Tags: c#, security, authentication, overriding

I need to override "CreateUserAndAccount(string userName, string password, object propertyValues = null, bool requireConfirmationToken = false)" method in WebSecurity Class in C#

Answer (score 0):

You can't override non-virtual methods in c#, this is `CreateUserAndAccount` method signature:

```
public static string CreateUserAndAccount(
string userName,
string password,
Object propertyValues,
bool requireConfirmationToken)
```

This method isn't virtual,so it's not possible.you can look at here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx

Instead of this you can create your own membership system: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730(v=vs.100).aspx